# What version of MS Word has the innate ability to save documents as PDF?

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, save-as

i am a software programmer seeking to know this particular information. I tried with 2k7, there was no such feature. Is this feature there for ms word 2010?

Comment: If you just require the ability to make a .doc into a .pdf and don't have ms word 2010, look at openoffice or as mentioned by Randolph, PDF Creator is an excellent option (but this requires you have at least one version of ms word).

Answer (score 7):

Yes, this is a new feature in MS-Word 2010.

I still prefer to install PDF Creator ( http://www.pdfforge.org/ ) so that all applications can print to a PDF file.

Answer (score 5):

It was doable in 2007 via a Microsoft provided add-in, but it's native in Office 2010.

Comment: It became native with 2007 SP1, with 2007 RTM it needed an additional install.

Comment: @Richard Ahh, very good, I didn't realise that. Good to know (though mostly irrelevant for me these days.) :)